# Word for to have the same thing become different

Tags: single-word-requests

I know there is word "discriminate" meaning to constitute the difference,
but it's usually used in negative sense. 
So what are the neutral and positive words?

Comment: a sample sentence please

Comment: Note that discriminate does not mean "constitute" (ie. make up or define) the difference, but it means to recognise the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "to differentiate (between)" or "to distinguish."

Comment: I'd plus one this with a bit more filling in as described in this boards guidelines.  On the mark I believe.\

Comment: Avoid writing single line answer. I'll suggest you to follow the guidelines directing EL & U. Read- [How do I write a good answer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) It will help you trailer your answer. Remember, healthy answer attracts healthy responses.

Answer (score 1):

[*Discriminate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discriminate), on its own, is completely neutral:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *transitive verb*
>   **1 a** : to mark or perceive the distinguishing or peculiar features of
>   // Depth perception may be defined as the ability to appreciate or *discriminate* the third dimension …
>   — H. G. Armstrong
>   **1 b** : DISTINGUISH, DIFFERENTIATE
>   // *discriminate* hundreds of colors
>   **2** : to distinguish by discerning or exposing differences : to recognize or identify as separate and distinct
>   // *discriminate* right from wrong
>   *especially* : to distinguish from another like object
>   // *discriminate* the individual voices in the choir

It's only when you use it *in combination with* another word, normally when using its *intransitive* verb form, that it can be taken in a normative sense—but that sense can be positive just as easily as negative:

> *intransitive verb*
>   **1 a** : to make a distinction
>   // *discriminate* among historical sources
>   // *discriminates* between literary fiction and popular fiction
>   **1 b** : to use good judgment
>   **2** : to make a difference in treatment or favor on a basis other than individual merit
>   // *discriminate* in favor of your friends
>   // *discriminate* against a certain nationality

Note the final examples of *discriminate* ***in favour of*** and *discriminate* ***against***. It's the context and words that follow *discriminate* that can give it a negative sense—not *discriminate* itself.

Another use of it is in an adjectival sense where people can say that somebody has *discriminating taste*—and that's used as a positive compliment.

Answer (score 0):

"Discern" carries a neutral to slightly positive meaning.

In [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discern) it appears to be neutral:

1a : to detect with the eyes
discerned a figure approaching through the fog
b : to detect with senses other than vision
discerned a strange odor

2 : to recognize or identify as separate and distinct : DISCRIMINATE
discern right from wrong

3 : to come to know or recognize mentally
unable to discern his motives

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discernment_of_Spirits) it appears to have a positive slant:

"Discernment" is considered a spiritual gift in a wide range of Christian circles.

Comment: Avoid writing single line answer. I'll suggest you to follow the guidelines directing EL & U. Read- [How do I write a good answer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) It will help you trailer your answer. Remember, healthy answer attracts healthy responses.

Comment: Hi G&G, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *discern* (linked to the source). For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)